# How to fix 'Background of div issue on hovering using CSS Clip-Path'

Tags: html, css

I'm working on CSS animation using `clip-path` were when I hover over span element the other div expands in a `circular manner`.The Hovering works fine but i'm facing issue as background is not totally covering the element.

Below is the gif image which shows issue i'm facing.
[image: Gif Image]

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body{
    background: #DCF5FF;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.container{
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.inner{
    background: rgba(7,218,165,1);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    /* height: 300px; */
    clip-path: circle(10% at 90% 52%);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

.inner > h1{
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
}

.inner > p{
    color:white;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.inner:hover{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
    background: #00B6FF;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.inner:hover > .wrapper{
    
}

.inner > span{
    float:right;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: color .5s;
    margin-right: 4%; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CSS Clip-Path</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <span>i</span>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Hey</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga molestiae adipisci qui temporibus optio eius voluptas consectetur cumque quis quasi fugit nobis dolor tenetur, harum nisi, molestias quisquam! Necessitatibus, ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are making the element position:absolute so it won't affect the height of the parent thus won't be covered by the background

Comment: @Temani Afif  So what do you recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it has to do with the fact that you put `position:absolute` on class `.wrapper`, which was overriding the attributes you had put in class `.inner`. See below another attempt that I believe is closer to what you intended to do.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body{
    background: #DCF5FF;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    background: rgba(7,218,165,1);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    clip-path: circle(8% at 90% 15%);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

.inner h1{
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
}

.inner p{
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.inner:hover{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
    background: #00B6FF;
}

.wrapper{
}
.inner:hover > .wrapper{
    
}

.inner span{
    float:right;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: color .5s;
    margin-right: 4%; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CSS Clip-Path</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <span>i</span>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Hey</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga molestiae adipisci qui temporibus optio eius voluptas consectetur cumque quis quasi fugit nobis dolor tenetur, harum nisi, molestias quisquam! Necessitatibus, ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Pater noster, qui es in caelis, sanctificetur nomen tuum, adveniat regnum tuum, fiat voluntas tua, sicut in caelo et in terra.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding a background color to `.inner p`

I hope it helps.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body{
    background: #DCF5FF;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.container{
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.inner{
    background: rgba(7,218,165,1);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    /* height: 300px; */
    clip-path: circle(10% at 90% 52%);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

.inner > h1{
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
}

.inner p{
    background: #DCF5FF;
    /*color:white;*/
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.inner:hover{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
    background: #00B6FF;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.inner:hover > .wrapper{
    
}

.inner > span{
    float:right;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: color .5s;
    margin-right: 4%; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CSS Clip-Path</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <span>i</span>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Hey</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga molestiae adipisci qui temporibus optio eius voluptas consectetur cumque quis quasi fugit nobis dolor tenetur, harum nisi, molestias quisquam! Necessitatibus, ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may notice that background also changes when hovered. Add background to `p` is not a proper solution and i also want to know the reason why is it behaving that way.